# jquery toggleClass not working

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

For some reason the toggleClass function does not seem to be working.

I have a table row with a class "nodrag" - being used with tableDnD plugin:

```
<tr id="1" class="nodrag">
<!--Some tds and stuff-->       
</tr>
```

When I click a link I want to toggle the class on and off with the following code which is in the $(document).ready function:

```
$("#reorder").click(function(event) {
    $("#1").toggleClass("nodrag");

    if ($(this).text()=='Reorder')
    {
        $(this).text("Done reordering");
    } else {
        $(this).text("Reorder");
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I know the click event fires because the text of the link changes.  I also know the selection of the row works because if I do something else with it like - $("#1").text("test") - that works.

It just seems to a problem with toggleClass.  I've searched everywhere though and found nothing that helps me.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What happens that shouldn't or doesn't happen that should? What makes you think that `.toggleClass()` isn't working?

Comment: which version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: I would recommend against using an element with an id of `1`... do you have any other elements with the same id? And have you confirmed that the class is not changing as it should via Firebug or other developer tools?

Comment: what does changing the class do ? what i mean is ... is there some visual effect ? have you used a debugger to see if the class is present still ? (oh and dont use IDs of just numbers not officially supported)

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net with some example code for us to see? We need more detail on the "<!--Some tds and stuff-->".

Comment: Yh the reason I know its not working is because if I inspect the code the class is still there.  Its not just the visual effect that is missing

Comment: What do you want to do? $("#1").toggleClass("nodrag") will do nothing if the existing class itself is "nodrag". What are you toggling here?

Comment: its works perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/C7xEN/

Comment: The `id` you're using, `1`, is an [invalid CSS `id` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). In CSS, `id` values cannot start with a digit. (This also [used to be true in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) up through HTML4; HTML5 [opens them up](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute).) Since jQuery uses CSS selectors, strongly recommend sticking with CSS rules for them. But regardless, WFM: http://jsbin.com/omefig

Comment: *"Yh the reason I know its not working is because if I inspect the code the class is still there."* **How** are you inspecting the code? If it's "view source," that's **not** the current state of the DOM, that's the markup as of when it was fetched from the server. To see the current DOM, use a proper debugger.

Comment: Sorry guys.
The problem seems to be with chromes hard refresh not doing anything which I was previously unaware of so even though id changed this it wasn't working. 

Does anyway know the table drag and drop plug in and how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a live demo that is working perfect for me

http://jsfiddle.net/Yjqkn/

Give it a try and let me know what is different between this code and yours.

**P.S:** 
you should always avoid naming your IDs with plain numbers, if you are inforced to do so, prefix it with any letter(s) before the number ex:*TblRow1, txt2*. but it's always recommended to name your controls with meaningful words ex: *txtUsername, lnkDelete,* etc.

Comment: Thanks. The toggleclass does seem to be working now.
The effect Im trying to gain is toggling the table drag and drop plug in on and off but this is not working

Comment: ok cool, just pick the best response and mark it as **answer**, so you reward back the community. :)

Answer (score 1):

It look like you entering stuff in you `<tr>` tag not in the `<td>` tag of the `tr`
I checked it work fine if you put the content inside `<td>` tag.
See here http://jsfiddle.net/QjjGD/1/

Comment: No, he's replacing the content of some `#reorder` element he hasn't shown, not the `tr`. He's said he's putting `td` elements and such in, so this basically comes down to "works for me," which is not an answer.